# No data found in my ngTableParams in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use ng-table component

***In my bower.json:***

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
...
    "ng-table": "~0.3.3"
  }
}
```

***In my index.html:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="test" ng-controller="TitleCtrl">
<head>
...
    <script src="bower_components/ng-table/ng-table.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-table/ng-table.css"/>
...
</head>
<body>

<ng-include src="'menu/menu.html'"></ng-include>

<div ng-view style="padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

***In my table.html:***

```
<form class="form-horizontal narrow" role="form">
   <div ng-controller="PropertiesCtrl">
        <p><strong>Page:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}</p>
        <p><strong>Count per page:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}</p>

        <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
                <td data-title="'Name'">{{user.name}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Age'">{{user.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

***In my properties.js:***

```
var propertiesModule = angular.module('test.properties', ['ngTable']);

propertiesModule.controller('PropertiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'PropertiesService', 'ApplicationService', 'PlatformService', 'Page', '$filter', 'ngTableParams', function ($scope, $routeParams, PropertiesService, ApplicationService, PlatformService, Page, $filter, ngTableParams) {
...
    $scope.on_edit_unit = function () {            
var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                {name: "Enos", age: 34}];

            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10           // count per page
            }, {
                total: data.length, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));


          }
            });
            console.log( data);
            console.log( $scope.tableParams);

        });
    };
...
```

When I log in the console **$scope.tableParams**:

> ngTableParams {data: Array[0], parameters: function, settings:
>   function, page: function, total: function…}

Why there is no data in my **ngTableParams**?

***UPDATE init a PLUNKER:***

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/GN9kQoBbgWbTHw1DtkZI)

Comment: Could you set-up a plnkr so we can see the code in action, but without testing it looks like your ng-repeat is incorrect. Have you tried just using data instead or $data ?

Comment: @rawco_de i have init a PLUNKER

Comment: @Mercer the plunker doesn't match the code posted in your question.  no `on_edit_unit` function.  no logging.

Comment: @j.wittwer i can't init the same in Plunker